# How to wait for an element to appear or disappear using vaadin testbench

Tags: java, vaadin7

I'm new to Vaadin TestBench. I've good knowledge on selenium. While exploring vaadin i came to Element Query API which Vaadin TestBench uses to locate the elements. I want to know how to wait for a specified Element to appear or disappear. Please see below code -

In my application, there is button called 'ClickToProcess'. I'm able to click it using following code

> $(ButtonElement.class).caption("ClickToProcess").first().click();

Now after clicking on above button, processing will be started at backend and after 10 to 15 seconds 'OpenProcessedDocument' button will be displayed. once button is displayed i'm able to access the button using following statement:

> $(ButtonElement.class).caption("OpenProcessedDocument").first().click();

My question is how to wait until 'OpenProcessedDocument' button is displayed using vaadin testbench element query API.

Answer (score 0):

This is the main feature of TestBench library.

To make TestBench library work, you have to use/instantiate TestBenchDriverProxy.

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("focusmanager.testmode", true);
driver = TestBench.createDriver(new FirefoxDriver(profile));
```

Then calling these two methods one after another should do fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just sleep the thread in your test

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(15000); // wait 15 s
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
 // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/testbench/creatingtests/testbench-special.html#testbench.special.waituntil

```
waitUntil(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//button[@title='Debug message log']"));
```